# A variable gets lost from $_POST

Tags: php

there is a client program which generates POST request toward my site. It goes well, but then a variable is big (about 1MB) and it simply gets lost! It doesn't exists. I check this: `echo ini_get('post_max_size')` its 32M so it cant be the error...

Comment: did you check the webserver's own limits? php can't do anything to override those.

Comment: umm what should I check?

Comment: You may want to check the apache or nginx configurations (or whatever web server you may be using), as everything that gets to php needs to go through them.

Comment: Are there multiple 1MB variables?

Comment: Try `echo ini_get('memory_limit');`

Comment: Is this 1MB variable a base64 encoded file by chance? If so then you may need to set it up to handle proper file uploads because those write to the disk in chunks so they do not max out your memory.

Comment: yea, its a base64 encoded content :) there are about 3 variables, the other two are just a little thinggy

Comment: have you checked the upload_max_filesize in the PHP.ini? It might be the culprit

Comment: Any error messages in the web-server or PHP error logs?